# How do I dynamically adding a collapsible div element on a web form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html file whose skeleton is as follows:

```
   <div id ="QBForm">
      <h3>Query1</h3>    
      <div class ="QBSubForm">...</div>
    </div>
```

I have a "AddQuery" button and on clicking that, I want to add another subform to the existing form and here's how I do that:

```
    $("#AddQuery").click(function (event) {
        var querysubform = $(".QBSubForm").html();                
        $("<h3>Query2</h3>" + querysubform).appendTo("#QBForm");                
    });
```

And I have this in my jQuery Ready() function:

```
 $("#QBForm").accordion();
```

But every time, I click on my add query button, the subform is added but it is not collapsible, its just its own static thing.

How do I add a sub-form and make each sub-form collapsible?

Comment: A jsfiddle would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing accordion with active: false and collapsible: true.

I haven't really tested the code below, but try:

```
 $("#QBForm").accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true });
```

if you do not set collapsible to true, jQuery UI will set at least one section open.

Answer (score 0):

Use `refresh` method of accordion to include dynamically added content.

Then if you want the new section opened you could also set the last panel to active by using `-1` as index

```
$("#AddQuery").click(function (event) {
    var querysubform = $(".QBSubForm").html();                
    $("<h3>Query2</h3>" + querysubform).appendTo("#QBForm");

     /* only refresh*/
     $("#QBForm").accordion('refresh');  

     /* refresh and set new panel active */
    $("#QBForm").accordion('refresh').accordion( "option", "active", -1 );; 

});
```

[Accordion Refresh docs()](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh)